# UIImageView to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I get images for JSON.like this:-

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *diction in al)
    {
        NSString *geting =[diction valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
        NSLog(@"dealimage is %@",geting);

        NSData *getdata=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:geting]];
        NSLog(@"good day %@",getdata);
        dataimages=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata];
        NSLog(@"dataimages %@",dataimages);

        [imagesarray addObject:dataimages];

     }
    NSLog(@"images array is array%@",imagesarray);
     NSLog(@"dataimages 8images %@",dataimages);
}
```

When i print images array it show like this:-

```
images array is array(
    "<UIImage: 0x7539b70>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7176e00>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7182960>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7185d40>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7541d00>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7186e30>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7186ff0>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7187410>"
)
```

What I tried is NSString to pass to NSData via Base64String and then NSData pass to UIImage and then UIImage pass to the NSMutablearray(imagearray).Now i pass the this array to UITableViewCell
like is:-

```
cell.imageView.image = [imagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But images are not display in UITableViewCell So Please give me any idea about my problem .
Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Are you reloading the tableView after parsing the data?

Comment: @Morpheus jest i try to Display Json images on UITableViewCell

Comment: If you have created the tableview datasource before the actual parsing of data, you have to reload the data for displaying it in tableView after you are getting response

Comment: Dont freeze UI, use some async method for loading images.

Comment: tableview.dataSource=Self; try like this.

Comment: just one line `[yourtableview reloadData]`; after complete your for loop.

Comment: AFNetworking will help you more with that. Just call your variables normally. imagesArray for example.

Comment: @Chinttu'RoxeN'Ramani thanks so much i got output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSLog(@"images array is array%@",imagesarray);

 yourTableView.dataSource = self;//or your object

 [yourTableView reloadData];
```

will make table view to refresh the data.

**if you didn't set the dataSource then table view will not look for table data to show.**

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blegspot thanks for Reply plz tell where it placed your code i am  new to this

Comment: connectionDidFinishLoading method's last code is the above part

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blegspot [table reloadData] jest placed after loop i got output thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way of loading image in to Table-view from Json is wrong. Better to load array with imageURL and load its Image from URL in to the `CellForRowAtIndex`: method

For example:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *diction in al)
    {
        NSString *geting =[diction valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
        NSLog(@"dealimage is %@",geting);
        [imagesarray addObject:geting]; // here adding image URL in side the Array

     }  

  [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

and CellForAtIndex:

```
  cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];
```

And for better smooth parformance use asynchronous image loading with help of [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or many other library that load you image from url with catch and performance faster.

Comment: i know that i just suggest to load image with url in side to CellForRowIndexPath method.

Comment: @NitinGohel thanks for Reply but i tried as you said but i am not getting image on UITableViewCell Please give me any idea about my problem